# Ocaml stdin interface

Tags: user-interface, stack, ocaml, stdin

I need to process user input from stdin with ocaml. User will enter commands until he types quit and then the program finishes. How to do this? I know how to program in imperative, but I want to learn functional. The user is supposed to manipulate data from a stack based on his commands. Also I want to do like a parser to process user commands.

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of something you could write using OCaml stack library. It's far from perfect and it could be improved in many ways, but the general structure is here.

The most important part as far as your question is concerned is the `loop` function. It reads a line from the standard input, and uses a pattern-matching to either end the program, or evaluate the given and command, and recursively call itself to wait for another command.

The `eval` function uses a pattern-matching on the given arguments to do the right thing. You can find documentation for the `Stack` module [here](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stack.html).

```
let stack = Stack.create ()

let eval args =
  match args with
  | ["push"; v] -> Stack.push v stack
  | ["pop"] -> begin try print_endline (Stack.pop stack) with
      | Stack.Empty -> print_endline "Stack is empty"
    end
  | ["show"] -> Stack.iter print_endline stack
  | _ -> print_endline "Unrecognized command"

let rec loop () =
  match read_line () with
  | "quit" -> print_endline "Bye"
  | _ as command -> eval (String.split_on_char ' ' command); loop ()


let () =
  loop ()
```

**Note**: I usually don't really like the idea of giving a full solution to a question that doesn't show a lot of research, but hey, you have to start somewhere when you're new to functional programming.

**Note 2**: This code will only work for `string` stacks. If you intend to store a different type, say `int`s, or if you want it to be polymorphic, you'll need to tweak that code a little bit.

**EDIT**: According to a remark made in the comments, below is an improved version of the above code, which doesn't use a global variable stack.

```
let eval s args =
  match args with
  | ["push"; v] -> Stack.push v s
  | ["pop"] -> begin try print_endline (Stack.pop s) with
      | Stack.Empty -> print_endline "Stack is empty"
    end
  | ["show"] -> Stack.iter print_endline s
  | _ -> print_endline "Unrecognized command"

let rec loop s =
  match read_line () with
  | "quit" -> print_endline "Bye"
  | _ as command -> eval s (String.split_on_char ' ' command); loop s


let () =
  loop (Stack.create ())
```

Comment: Well! That's something to start. Thanks a lot for answering. Hey, I really do research, I'm reading the book real world ocaml, but I (still) don't found an example really simple like this one. Also, I found a way of doing this but in a more 'imperative' way, using references, but that was not my point, because I want to do as functional as it can be. Again, thank you!

Comment: Good, Real World OCaml is probably one of the best resources out there. Learning how to "think" functional is quite the challenge, tbh. And please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Using a mutable/global variable stack is not really in the spirit of the functional paradigm. More conventional way would be to add a parameter that will act as the stack to the eval function.

Comment: Agreed. That's where the "it's far from perfect and could be improved in many ways" part kicks in.

Comment: Here you're hiding side effects in the Stack module (which is no re-entrant).
In fact i was more thinking at something like : 
  let eval s args =
  match args,stack with
  | ["push"; v], s -> v::s
  ...
Wich uses a pure functionnal structure (a list), to act as the stack.

Comment: Yes, but removing **all** side-effects isn't always the way to go, imo. Here, modifying the stack is exactly what we want to do, so I'm okay with having side-effects in this part of the code. Removing side-effects for the sake of it isn't what functional programming is about, if you ask me.

Comment: Perfect, It's really challenge to me imagine all withouth side effects comming from imperative. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: It's only something to get used to, just as you got used to imperative algorithms ;)

Comment: When I put this: let eval s args =
  match args with
  | ["push"; v] -> Stack.push v s
  | ["pop"] -> begin try print_endline (Stack.pop s) with
      | Stack.Empty -> print_endline "Stack is empty"
    end
  | ["show"] -> Stack.iter print_endline s
  | _ -> print_endline "Unrecognized command";; on ocaml interpreter, it says: Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type 'a Stack.t

Comment: I can do this with a list also, I will try that

Comment: Sorry for that, that happens only on the interpreter, but compiles perfectly. The answer works great thanks

Comment: I am doing this with a list, finally it's working but the values are not keeping on the list, every time the loop iterates the list goes empty. Do you know why is that? Why the stack you created are like a global variable? How to do this with a simple list? I want to use list because are a lot of functions to operate on the and are more useful for me

Comment: Well, without seeing what you've written, this is going to be be complicated. My guess is that you're not using the return value of the `eval` function you've written. In my example, it returns `unit`, because, as @ghilesZ pointed out, OCaml's `Stack` uses side-effects. If you want to use pure functional structures in you case, lists), `eval` is going to return a new stack every time.

Comment: Here's a solution using a list: https://gist.github.com/ghilesZ/b12465ec4c32fe42b8c9ae50e6b3f51f
It is purely functional and efficient. Note that the interal structure of the type Stack.t uses in fact a mutable list. So there is no crucial difference between the two implementation except the fact that this one will be side-effect free, with all the benefits that go with :)

Comment: I managed to do it by myself finally. It's incredible when things start to work in functional, really challenging but magical at the end. I'm starting to like it, thanks anyway for the response I will take a look!